# In Careers 2.0, the Gravatar on profiles tends to cover part of Current Positions

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, profile-page, design

This issue becomes even more accentuated than seen below when the page is being viewed on a smaller screen (a smartphone, for instance). It's not a huge issue, I suppose, but should also be pretty simple to fix.

[image: Part of current positions are covered by the gravatar.]

Comment: Note that this only happens on the edit view, because of that little "edit" link in the top right.  It should work properly on the employer / public views

Comment: Ah. I hadn't realized that. Much less of an issue then, methinks. Should have thought to check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this in edit mode.  It'll go out sometime tomorrow morning.